# How do I teach my linux command line manners?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, terminal, shell

Whenever I complete something in the command line while using Ubuntu and my computer does something of value to me, I enjoy saying thank you, just because it's the polite thing to do. A typical conversation might look something like this:

```
mtp-sendfile HamishAndyPodcast.mp3 /Music/podcasts
Sending file...
Progress: 17769768 of 17769768 (100%)
New file ID: 76098
sam@sams-laptop:~$ thanks
thanks: command not found
```

What's the best way to teach my PC a few manners and respond with something like "No problemo".

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Add this to ~/.bash_aliases or execute it on the commandline:

```
alias thanks='echo "No problemo dude!"'
```

Eg:

```
user@host:~$ alias thanks='echo "No problemo dude!"'
user@host:~$ thanks
No problemo dude!
```

You could also stick it in your ~/.bashrc.  If you add it to ~/.bash_aliases, make sure your ~/.bashrc has a section like this:

```
# Alias definitions.
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

Comment: `\\` infront of an alias will ignore the alias.

Comment: Can we do the same in windows?

Answer (score 5):

```
alias thanks='fortune zippy'
```

or

```
alias thanks='fortune fortunes'
```